# Android HTTPS error No Trusted Server Certificate

Tags: android, apache, ubuntu, ssl, https

I have an existing API server with HTTPS. When I access it from my Android app, it shows an HTTPS error: Untrusted server certificate. How can I access my HTTPS URL from my Android app?

Comment: Your question is unclear and does not have enough context to be answered. Please clarify it using the help section of StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue happens if your SSL certificate is not properly installed. This can happen for a number of reasons.

1. You might me using a self signed certificate.(To solve this you will need a certificate from a trusted CA).
2. If you have a valid certificate don't see a green sign in the mobile browser, it might me that you have not installed the complete certificate chain in Apache and one of the intermediate certificates is not trusted by the Android Browser(I have had issues like this previously).

The solution is to install the complete certificate chain in Apache and not just your domain certificate.

In Apache conf you will have to provide the following fields

```
SSLCertificateFile  <Certificate file path>
SSLCertificateKeyFile   <Key file path>
SSLCACertificatePath    <Intermediate bundle path>
```

You can refer to [this doc](https://in.godaddy.com/help/apache-install-a-certificate-centos-5238) to better understand.